# Zxing called from a web page: open callback url in new tab/window

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've followed [these instructions](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages) to scan barcodes from my web page using the app "Barcode scanner" by Zxing. After reading the code I need to pass it to the server, without leaving the original page (the actual behaviour is that callback url replaces the original page).

How can I do that?

That is:

1. can Barcode Scanner open the callback url in a new tab/window?
2. can Barcode Scanner call the server without using a tab (as in an ajax web service?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following those instructions you end up with a workflow like this:

- User clicks a scan button on your website
- Link opens a ZXing webpage

  - If Barcode Scanner is not installed, the user is prompted to install it
- ZXing webpage opens the ZXing app
- User scans the barcode using the ZXing app
- ZXing app closes and user is returned to ZXing webpage
- ZXing webpage redirects the user to the callback url with placeholders populated by barcode data

To answer your questions

> Can Barcode Scanner open the callback URL in a new tab/window?

No. Barcode Scanner cannot, because it doesn't seem to call the callback url directly. But clicking the scan button in your app could open the ZXing webpage in a new window and then the callback would (probably) be opened in that tab/window instead of the window where the button was clicked.

> Can Barcode Scanner call the server without using a tab?

I don't think so. That would only make sense in the case of realtime websites that are able to provide immediate feedback when the callback is invoked. Without that feedback the scan disappears into the ether and the user doesn't know if the callback succeeded or failed because of one of the myriad reasons that these things fail.

Comment: After several experiments, I've found that a new tab is opened and launches the app, then it closes. When a barcode is read, the app calls callback url, which replaces the last opened tab (which now is the original opener). Now I manage this by opening a second tab, which is used by the callback